# macOS 13 Ventura : bypass unidentified developer alert

Tags: mac, security, java, eclipse

I try to run the Eclipse 2023.03 (latest) for mac os x64 binary.

I got every time the *Unidentified Developer*  alert, so I'm unable to run Eclipse.

I tried :

- `sudo spctl --master-disable`, but it tells me that the option doesn't exist (unrecognized option). Indeed, the only option that exists (by using `-help`) that is similar is `--global-disable` (but not tested yet).
- On *Security and Privacy* settings, the "Everywhere" option never appears. Only *Mac App Store* and *Mac App Store and identfied developers*.
- After I try to open Eclipse, when I go back to *Security and Privacy* settings`, it ask me to allow` eclipsexxxx.so`. I check yes, but then I can't launch it (just the Eclipse logo appears then crash). On the logs I can see errors related to system policies on others librairies (.so) used by Eclipse.

How to proceed ?

Comment: The Eclipse code is signed so it should work fine with "App Store and identified developers" -  it certainly does for me. Did you download Eclipse from `https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/` - either the installer or one of the packages?

Comment: I use the Java EE dmg from the official web site. Unfortunately, it is not recognized at all ( https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2023-03/R/eclipse-java-2023-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg )

Comment: That download works fine on my 13.3.1 (a) Ventura.